# Progress bar unhide and load issue

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to get some jQuery working (i'm new to it). I'm trying to get the bar to show when a key is pressed in a textbox and then for the bar to load. I have the bar loading, but making it unhide and then start loading is causing an issue, so far i have this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

        $('#progressbar').hide();

        var progress = setInterval(function () {
            var $bar = $('#bar');

            $('#<%=tb_NarLogSearch.ClientID%>').keyup(function () {

                $('#progressbar').show();
                if ($bar.width() == 400) {
                    clearInterval(progress);
                    $('.progress').removeClass('active');
                } else {
                    $bar.width($bar.width() + 40);
                }
                $bar.text($bar.width() / 4 + "%");
            }, 800);
        })
```

I'm at a loss really, I've read that using keyup means it doesn't need an if statement, but taking it out breaks it completely. The issue i'm having is that the bar isn't showing when a key is pressed! Any ideas?

FYI: I might try an AJAX loading bar as i'm trying to indicate the progress of SQL query but wanted to try something different.

Comment: What is the specific issue you are running into?

Comment: That would be helpful! the bar isn't showing when a key is pressed!

Comment: I'd probably edit my question to include that info! ;) Also are you looking for any keypress or a specific one?

Comment: Just done it! any keypress really

Comment: Okay I suspect your problem has to do with control focusing, from the jquery doc: A keypress event handler can be attached to any element, but the event is only sent to the element that has the focus. Focusable elements can vary between browsers, but form controls can always get focus so are reasonable candidates for this event type.

Comment: Wouldn't the textbox that the user is typing into be the active focus element though?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your comments I'm going to suggest that instead of using keyup, you can use keypress instead. It seems like it would be a better fit and be a bit more robust

Here is the documentation:

https://api.jquery.com/keypress/

And here is a sample implementation

```
<form>
  <fieldset>
    <input id="target" type="text" value="Hello there">
  </fieldset>
</form>
<div id="other">
  Trigger the handler
</div>
```

The event handler can be bound to the input field:

```
$( "#target" ).keypress(function() {
  console.log( "Handler for .keypress() called." );
});
```